# Reverse DNS Lookup from the Command Line

Tags: domain, command-line-interface, ip-address, reverse-dns

I'd like to get a list of all domains pointed to a certain IP address.  Is there a way to get this information from the command line?

Nothing like "host", "nslookup" or "dig -x".  Those return the hostname of the IP address which, while helpful, is only part of what I want returned.

Edit for more information:
An example of a website that returns this information is http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/?hostname=74.125.47.104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to get this information at all, because there isn't a centralized authoritative repository for this information.  Anyone that owns a domain name can create an A record or CNAME that points to a given IP address.  The owner of the DNS records doesn't necessarily have to have any control over the IP addresses.

For example, Microsoft could create a series of A records named google.microsoft.com that pointed at the public IP addresses for google.com.  Other than already knowing it exists, there's no easy way to take Google's IP addresses and find out that google.microsoft.com exists.

Comment: I've edited the question to show an example of what I'm looking for: http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/?hostname=74.125.47.104

Comment: My answer still stands.  domaintools.com must be building their own database of this information via some other method.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I could just write a script to google for an ip address and take the results and verify them by pinging the domain for an incomplete list.  Looks like that's all I can do, yes?

Comment: That or see if DomainTools has an API for querying their database.  FWIW, it looks like DomainTools is doing it by building a DB based on A records of the domains themselves, so it's pretty incomplete.  For an IP address that I control, it said there were 12 domains.  It's correct in that there are 12 domains with A records for the domain name pointing to the IP, but incorrect in that it missed subdomains and domains forwarded by GoDaddy.

Comment: afrazier is correct- the tool you are pointing to is relatively worthless for the reasons specified.  You also have to remember that there is nothing stopping me from registering mysuperspecialsearch.net and pointing it to google and the only way you will know what I am pointing to is when you query my DNS records.