# Manual reverse DNS lookup

Tags: domain-name-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse DNS Lookup from the Command Line](https://serverfault.com/questions/135247/reverse-dns-lookup-from-the-command-line)

Is there a way to do manual reverse dns loookup? For example the way we use dig or nslookup. How do look up a domain name if I have the IP address?

Edit:
When I dig, for example an A record for google.com. I get corresponding IPs to google.com. If I have an IP of some server is there a way using DNS lookup tools to get the domain name of the server?

Comment: oh damn. Yes duplicate for sure.

Comment: There isn't necessarily a single Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN - includes the hostname) for the server.  The server may have multiple NICS, multiple IP addresses, and multiple DNS records pointing at one or more of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the -x option with dig:

```
 # dig +short -x 64.34.119.12
 stackoverflow.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard UNIX / Linux utilities such as nslookup, dig or hosts to find out reverse DNS of a given IP address.

host ip

or

nslookup ip

Answer (score 1):

nslookup *ip_address*  will do a [reverse DNS lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), but it will only return an entry if there is a PTR record available for the IP address.  This will not necessarily return all the domain names that are linked to the IP address.